# android emulator refuse to run armeabi native program, why?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-emulator, abi

I use bluestacks & MEmu to test my native programs built from NDK, x86 programs are well supported, but both refuse to run even a simple HelloWorld which is armeabi or armeabi-v7a.

Bluestacks returns error code 255 after the program launched, and MEmu complains `not executable: magic 7F45`. However, some games which have only armeabi-v7a libs can run normally on these two emulators, why does this happen?

Comment: it's clear that you can't run armeabi libs on x86 emulator. I prsonally don't believe that something that has only armeabi-v7a can run on x86.

Comment: Running ARM binaries on x86 Android environments requires `libhoudini` from Intel. I do not know whether Intel is licensing that to emulator developers.

Comment: Yes, there is so called ARM binary translation from Intel after a quick google, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation. But I am still confused by the fact many games have only armeabi libs run well on bluestacks, meanwhile my single program cannot.